# Как сайты, и сервисы определяют что ты робот?

Tags: node.js, защита, ddos

Написал я парсер сайта, на Node JS, сижу вот сейчас отлаживаю вроде работает, спарсил 67 объявлений. Проблема в другом, я начел числиться в Ddos защитах у других сайтов, как робот. Причем некоторые так и говорят из вашей сети идет подозрительный трафик, давай типа капчу проходи.
Я паршу вроде, не гугл а обычный сайт, причем у меня тайминги(время между запросами) аж 11 секунд, node сервер стоит на виртуальной машине.

И все равно меня как то вычислили.
Как так господа? Как они это делают? Как мне тогда маскироваться, я ведь не ddos-ер?

Я использую got, и puppeteer для сложных моментов.

Comment: Сейчас это уже норма, сейчас везде капчу пихают и с поводом и без повода. У меня вот гугл почти каждый 10-й поисковой запрос капчу свою сует. И каждый раз я ему доказываю что я не робот, а он мне обратное. Причем это обычный домашний ip, через vpn там совсем все печально.

Comment: Это то понятно, если домашний интернет то куча народу могут на оной ip сидеть, и кто его знает что они могут делать. Но у меня капчи почти нет, как только начал дома работать, сразу началось. Я паршу вообще левый сайт, не поисковики. Не понимаю как они понимают и как следят за тобой и еще с другими сайтами делятся.

Comment: вот я серьезно не понимаю, почему парсеры сайтов так популярны?

Comment: Может помочь: https://github.com/paulirish/headless-cat-n-mouse

Comment: vsemozhebuty, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы можете использовать `User-Agent` по умолчанию (Что-то вроде `node.js v1.2.3 - Needle v4.5.6`) или не использовать совсем.
2. Так же вы можете не применять `Cookie` отправляемые сайтом и получается что при нескольких запросах подряд на один сайт у вас будут приходить "чистые" запросы несколько раз подряд что смотрится крайне странно.
3. У вас может быть крайне странное поведение. Например человек на доске объявлений, даже если применил фильтры, всё равно не будет открывать и просматривать более пятидесяти объявлений да ещё, и выделяя на каждое объявление 11 секунд.
4. На сайте стоит защита от какого-нибудь CloudFlare, который достаточно быстро определяет "неправильных" клиентов и соответственно, везде где стоит он же, вы автоматически персоной нон грата.

Comment: Спасибо, за подробный ответ! Походу заморачиватся нет смысла, и проще использовать частую смену прокси, как советовал Inventor. Если я буду менять userAgent для каждого proxy это защитит мой IP? Может есть что то еще?

Comment: User-Agent не связан с ip, но лучше использовать аналогичный тому что используют клиентские браузеры. Если хочется максимально мимикрировать под живого человека, то можете попробовать [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ Ein. Скорее всего сайты смотрят на ваш ip и видят, что с этого ip идёт много запросов и поведение этого ip не соответствует поведению человека. Вы можете использовать прокси и каждый раз менять свой ip адрес, чтобы сайты не знали, что это вы